# WPF Ordering DataBinding in nested user controls

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have two user controls: 'Flags' and 'FlagOption'.  'FlagOption' is nested in an ItemsControl in the 'Flags' control like so:

Flags Control:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:Flags}, Path=FlagOptions}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:FlagOption FlagValue="{Binding}" Field="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:Flags}, Path=Field}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FieldProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Field), typeof(TagInterface.LongFlags), typeof(Flags));

public TagInterface.LongFlags Field
{
    get { return (TagInterface.LongFlags)GetValue(FieldProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FieldProperty, value); }
}

public IEnumerable<Enum> FlagOptions
{
    get
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(Field.FieldValue.GetType()).Cast<Enum>();
    }
}
```

FlagOption Control:

```
<CheckBox FlowDirection="LeftToRight" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:FlagOption}}"/>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FlagValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FlagValue), typeof(Enum), typeof(FlagOption));
public static readonly DependencyProperty FieldProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Field), typeof(TagInterface.LongFlags), typeof(FlagOption));

public Enum FlagValue
{
    get { return (Enum)GetValue(FlagValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FlagValueProperty, value); }
}

public TagInterface.LongFlags Field
{
    get { return (TagInterface.LongFlags)GetValue(FieldProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FieldProperty, value); }
}

public bool IsChecked
{
    get
    {
        // Accessing Field Property here is null because it is bound AFTER IsChecked field
        return false;
    }
    set
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that in the FlagOption control the "Field" Dependency Property is being bound AFTER the IsChecked Property, so the Field property is null in the Getter of the IsChecked property.  If debug and step over the error the "Field" Dependency property eventually gets bound, but it's too late.

Can I control the order of the binding somehow?  Why isn't the Field Dependency Property binding before my IsChecked Property?

Comment: I faced the same issue many times, and the best what I found for myself is to set bindings in xaml in right order

Comment: Why do you need to access the Field property inside the getter of the IsChecked property? This is not really the proper way properties should work. You definitely want to avoid a design where the order of binding evaluation matters (b/c you can't really, nor should you try to control it).

Comment: I need to access the Field property in the getter of IsChecked because that's where I wanted to perform my bitwise logic to determine if the flag is checked, and alternatively where I would do the reverse logic to set the value on my model when the user checks/unchecks the field.